# How to create a async::thread on Mac in C++11?

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, asynchronous

is it possible to start a async thread on a c++ programm?

like

```
std::async(function);
```

on mac it doesn't work for me and the main Programm waits for a return.

I want to start my async Thread in the beginning from my Program and Stop it with closing... without any syncs or something like that.

I'm using C++ 11 with the XCode.
would be great if u have a solution for me.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe you want to use a regular [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)?

Comment: No, i needed a async thread, i cant sync the thread, here is why:

In my thread is a request loop to a URL, to get a json, 
if i sync this thread, my programm is lagging a little bit.

Comment: But if you create a thread it *is* "async", it will run independent from your main thread. However, it seems to me that you want to use [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) with the [*`async` launch policy*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch), then it will run in the background and you can get the result any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify that you want the thread to run asynchronously by passing [std::launch::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch) as the first parameter. Otherwise the runtime system can choose to *defer* the launch:

```
#include <future>

void function()
{
    // do asynchronous stuff.
}

int main()
{
    std::future<void> fut = std::async(std::launch::async, function);

    // do other stuff

    fut.get(); // synchronize threads
}
```

That should work.

Comment: Why not `auto fut = ...`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Probably for clarity in this case.

Comment: @NathanOliver I would use `auto` but in the example that would obscure the *type* for the OP. So it seemed better to leave it explicit.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm just a beginner and new on OSX.

Comment: @Galik But the type is not necessarily `std::future<void>`.  `std::async()` returns `std::future<std::result_of_t<std::decay_t<Function>(std::decay_t<Args>...)>>` in C++ 14

Comment: @NathanOliver Indeed. But that would be even mor confusing. So for my example I chose to present a function that returns void.

Comment: Sorry, that was wrong. 

It has the same result like std::async, i can see in my debug log, that the Program is only running in the loop from the "async" thread. 

I cant use the "fut.get".

Let me explain why:

I have a program which have a gui to use some parameters, all the time (in the background!!!) i have to check a URL to have a look if some of the parameters are changed. 

If i do the change with a thread and do a .get() my programm have to wait for the request from the server... result = "little lags".

Hopefully that was understandable ;)

Comment: because of that i created a async funktion which is always in the background without any sync and ask's the server for the URL. In the main, is a little toogle function which will copy the Requested data's in a Global Variable. This is to prevent that the variables are NULL while the request starts to write new Inputs in it. 

Hopefully that was understandble ;)

Comment: @TheRealLife Then you don't need to do the `get()` until the program closes. You can put the `std::future` object in a class that will last as long as you want to collect `urls` and then, when the GUI closes, signal the thread to stop looping and call the `get()`.